# How the shallow copy work with dictionary in dictionary in Python?

Tags: python

I have struggle when I write the function which it have the similar function as deep copy

```
recipes = {
"Butter chicken": {
    "chicken": 750,
    "lemon": 1,
    "cumin": 1,
    "paprika": 1,
    "chilli powder": 2,
    "yogurt": 250,
    "oil": 50,
    "onion": 1,
    "garlic": 2,
    "ginger": 3 }
}
recipes_copy = {}
for char, value in recipes.items():
    char_copy = char
    value_copy = value.copy()
    recipes_copy[char_copy] = value_copy
recipes_copy["Butter chicken"]["ginger"] = 300
print(recipes_copy["Butter chicken"]["ginger"])
print(recipes["Butter chicken"]["ginger"])
```

I don't understand why the shallow copy in line `value_copy = value.copy()` doesn't change the value when I change the value of copy dictionary `recipes_copy["Butter chicken"]["ginger"] = 300`
The output I got:

```
300
3
```

Comment: I'm sorry, could you clarify your question? You changed the value in the `recipes_copy` dictionary but not the `recipes` dictionary, what is your expected behaviour?

Comment: <obj>.copy() does a shallow copy of <obj>, but in the current case, it's the equivalent of a deep copy because "recipes" is a single-level structure.    Because of the deep copy, "recipes" and "recipes_copy" have no parts in common, so changing "recipes_copy" doesn't affect "recipes".

Comment: Sorry, as I know the shallow copy will change the original dict when the copy dict it change so I think that the original dict `recipes` will change to 300 instead of 3 as my output print

Comment: You are **not** doing a *shallow* copy of the `recipes` dictionary.

Comment: So when I shallow copy the `value` and change the copy of `value`.  It doesn't effect to the `recipes` right?

Comment: @NamNguyênTường  "as I know the shallow copy will change the original dict when the copy dict it change" **No**, when you change any copy, it doesn't affect the original. When you change an object *both copies are referring to* then you'll see that change reflected in *both*, obviously, that is all.

Comment: And note, `char_copy = char` **is not a copy at all**

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga you could go further and say assignment **never** makes a copy in Python, unless the expression you're assigning explicitly makes a copy.  But it's a moot point for immutable objects like strings and numbers since you can't tell the difference between the original and a copy anyway.

Comment: @MarkRansom yes, absolutely, assignment to a variable *never implicitly copies*. That is correct. OK, I suppose *never say never*, [there might be some hacky, metaprogramming way](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-module-attribute-access) to make a module object's namespace some custom mapping that implicitly copies any object. But barring that sort of craziness, I agree 100%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at your original dictionary. It consists of two levels of collections:

```
first level: dictionary (keys: Butter chicken)
    second level: dictionary (keys: chicken, lemon, ginger, etc)
```

The values of the second level are numbers. There is no need (and no effect) in copying them. Numbers do not contain further values.

In your code, you iterate over the first level of your collection (the dictionary that contains only the key "Butter chicken"). For each second level dictionary you create a shallow copy.
However, for the second level there is no difference between a deep and a shallow copy because the second level dictionary does not contain further collections that could be copied, just numbers.

You effectively create a copy of the first level dictionary by iterating it and copying it's values. You do the same for the second level dictionary.
Because you copied everything, there are no links between your original dictionary and your copy.
Therefore, the changes you make to the copy do not propagate back.

If you shallow copy the first-level dictionary, you get the behavior you are expecting:

```py
recipes = {
"Butter chicken": {
    "chicken": 750,
    "lemon": 1,
    # I took the freedom to shorten your recipe a bit :)
    "ginger": 3 }
}
print(recipes["Butter chicken"]["ginger"])  # prints 3

recipes_copy = recipes.copy()
recipes_copy["Butter chicken"]["ginger"] = 300

print(recipes_copy["Butter chicken"]["ginger"])  # prints 300
print(recipes["Butter chicken"]["ginger"])  # prints 300
```